# ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) FAILED_PRECONDITION: failed precondition: due to quota restrictions, cannot run builds in this region

Tags: deployment, gcloud

I am running tutorial example of deploying PHP to Cloud-Run from code:
https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy/deploy-php-service

When running command:
$ gcloud run deploy

I am getting this error:

> ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) FAILED_PRECONDITION: failed precondition:
> due to quota restrictions, cannot run builds in this region. Please
> contact support

Currently using SDK version: **458.0.1** (latest version downloaded from Google)
I checked some similar issues and succeed to workaround by downgrade the SDK to version 455 using the command:

```
$ gcloud components update --version 455.0.0
```

This indeed solve the problem and code was deployed,

The question that was not answered by previous issue for the same error is this:

**What settings is required for making latest SDK version to work correctly.
Looks like something is missing in the documentation. Downgrade is fine for now but is not an answer for future work.**

Thanks.